# Browser-mob Proxy is not capturing the network traffic with chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browsermob-proxy

I am using this code to integrate the browser mob proxy with maven dependency
net.lightbody.bmp browsermob-core 2.1.5

its not capturing the network requests at all, I am getting this kind of har file:

```
{
   "log":{
      "version":"1.2",
      "creator":{
         "name":"BrowserMob Proxy",
         "version":"2.1.0-beta-6-littleproxy",
         "comment":""
      },
      "pages":[
         {
            "id":"11",
            "startedDateTime":"2017-10-26T17:28:42.501+05:30",
            "title":"11",
            "pageTimings":{
               "comment":""
            },
            "comment":""
         }
      ],
      "entries":[],
      "comment":""
   }
}
```

---

```
package lenskart.tests;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer;
import net.lightbody.bmp.client.ClientUtil;
import net.lightbody.bmp.mitm.manager.ImpersonatingMitmManager;
import net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.CaptureType;

public class ProxyTestClass {

    @Test
    public static void main() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BrowserMobProxyServer browserMobProxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
        browserMobProxy.setTrustAllServers(true);
        browserMobProxy.setMitmManager(ImpersonatingMitmManager.builder().trustAllServers(true).build());
        browserMobProxy.start(0);

        System.out.println("Port Started On: " + browserMobProxy.getPort());
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/pankaj.katiyar/Desktop/Automation/Lenskart_Automation/tpt/drivers/chromedriver");

        browserMobProxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_HEADERS);

        WebDriver driver = getDriver_CapProxy(browserMobProxy);

        driver.get("http://www.lenskart.com");
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        driver.quit();

        browserMobProxy.stop();

        browserMobProxy.newHar("11");
        browserMobProxy.getHar().writeTo(new File("/Users/pankaj.katiyar/Desktop/Automation/Lenskart_Automation/har"));
        ;
        System.out.println("Loaded browser ");
    }


    public static WebDriver getDriver_CapProxy(BrowserMobProxyServer browserMobProxy) throws UnknownHostException {
        Proxy proxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(browserMobProxy);
        proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:" + browserMobProxy.getPort());

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");

        cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's two issues with your code.

First the selenium proxy is assigned to the capabilities, but the instance is never used. So either [assign the options to the capabilities](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities), or directly assign the selenium proxy to the options:

```
Proxy seleniumProxy  = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(browserMobProxy);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Second, you are calling `browserMobProxy.newHar` at the end of the recording when it should be at the beginning:

```
browserMobProxy.newHar("11");

driver.get("http://www.lenskart.com");
driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

browserMobProxy.getHar().writeTo(new File("/Users/pankaj.katiyar/Desktop/Automation/Lenskart_Automation/har"));

driver.quit();
browserMobProxy.stop();
```

Comment: After proxy is applied - I am getting :  This page isn’t working

www.google.co.in didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: It could be an issue with the redirection. Try with `https://www.google.com` instead of `http://www.google.com`

Answer (score 3):

I ran your code and only two changes you need are, change

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

to

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

And move `browserMobProxy.newHar("11");` before the navigate

```
browserMobProxy.newHar("11");
driver.get("http://www.lenskart.com");
```

Rest all is fine in your code. Once you do that Har is generated fine as shown in below screenshot

[image: Generated HAR]

Comment: After proxy is applied, I am getting - This page isn’t working

www.google.co.in didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: @PankajKumarKatiyar, let me check

Comment: Try removing the `setMitmManager` and `setTrustAllServers`. It works for me after that on https links also

Comment: Sorry, its not working, I tried after commenting these lines, browserMobProxy.setTrustAllServers(true);
browserMobProxy.setMitmManager(ImpersonatingMitmManager.builder().trustAllServers(true).build());   Keep on getting - This page isn’t working

Comment: I think I may have done some certificate setup for same in past, let me check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157860/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-pankaj-kumar-katiyar).

Comment: Hi, I am getting this same error, were you able to resolve this issue?